# is there a way to add characters to a stack?

Tags: java

Is there a way to add characters from a string to a stack without having to create your own push and pop methods?

Examples would be very appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just use a `Stack<char>`from `java.util.*`?

Comment: @us2012 Because it's illegal, you have to use ref type, in this case Character!

Comment: How would I successfully attempt to do add characters to a stack? @SergiiZagriichuk

Comment: @Jay answer below, use Stack of Character like this     String s = "your string";
            Stack<Character> d = new Stack<Character>();
            d.push(s.toCharArray()[0]); // add first symbol from string 'y'

Answer (score 8):

```
Stack<Character> myStack = new Stack<Character>();

char letter = 'a';
myStack.push((Character) letter);
```

Create a stack that contains `Character` objects, and cast your `char`s to `Character` before you insert them.

Java `Character` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Just like `int`s and `Integer`s, you need to wrap a primitive before you can insert it in to a data structure.

Edit: Apparently `Stack` is deprecated since it inherits from `Vector`. Here's why: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

As Mark Peters indicated, you should use `LinkedList` or `ArrayDeque`.

Comment: `Stack` is unofficially deprecated in favor of `Deque` implementations, like `LinkedList` and `ArrayDeque`.  Unfortunately they messed up by making `Stack` a concrete class and not the name of the interface.

Comment: so it isn't possible to accomplish this after all?

Comment: BTW, You have no to casting char to Caracters will be autoboxing

Answer (score 3):

I've decided to answer to this question because there are some misunderstanding...
So, 
There is `String`:

```
String s = "your string";
```

Create `Stack` or `List` (`LinkedList`) look to comment to Answer from Michael

```
Stack<Character> d = new Stack<Character>();
```

after all loop with `char` push logic

```
 for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        d.push(c);
    }
```

And that is all!!!